# Where does Python retrieve the <filename> traceback entry field from

Tags: python, intercept, traceback

Each traceback item has a format like:

```
File "<filename>", line xxx, in <module>
    line
```

I'm interested in changing the filename field (to something custom) for certain modules. Is this possible? I've tried modifying the `__file__` member of the module object, but that doesn't seem to be used when python generates the traceback stack.

Comment: Unless when `<filename>` is `<stdin>` and not a real file path (when the code is provided on stdin), it would not be desireable to replace the source file path as it would make debugging more difficult without the source file path from the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` module to get the filepath of many modules.  e.g.

```
>>> inspect.getabsfile(traceback)
'/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/traceback.py'
```

Knowing that the traceback comes from [traceback.print_stack()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html), we can then look to the definition of `print_stack()`:

```
279 def print_stack(f=None, limit=None, file=None):
280     """Print a stack trace from its invocation point.
281
282     The optional 'f' argument can be used to specify an alternate
283     stack frame at which to start. The optional 'limit' and 'file'
284     arguments have the same meaning as for print_exception().
285     """
286     print_list(extract_stack(_get_stack(f), limit=limit), file=file)
```

With "where is it defined?" out of the way, I'll save you the trouble of following the function calls around and suggest looking at [format_exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) and the [relevant examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples).  Without knowing specifically what you want to do with the traceback, I'd suggest looking at the [jinja2 source](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/debug.py) as it does quite a bit of traceback mangling.

Comment: It looks like you've got it figured and it's even the accepted answer but that's not it at all. Look at the answer I post

Comment: Despite what it looks like, the `traceback` module isn't actually what CPython uses to print tracebacks. It's a Python-level reimplementation of the functionality with subtle differences.

Answer (score 1):

The code that prints this line is inside CPython's code, in the function `tb_displayline()` of traceback.c:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Python/traceback.c#L511

The call stack is easy to follow:

`PyTraceBack_Print()` → `tb_printinternal()` → `tb_displayline()`

Looking at the code of those functions, it's not possible to mutate the code frame object from within the interpreter without tinkering with the sources of CPython. Also the `co_filename` attribute of a code frame is defined readonly: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/codeobject.c#L388

For info, `PyTraceBack_Print()` is called from two places:

- from `print_exception()` in Python/pythonrun.c
- from `write_unraisable_exc_file()` in Python/errors.c

So it's not possible to modify the filename of a module that has been imported from a file, because in this case the loader is `SourceFileLoader` which doesn't allow to modify the filename.
The source code for `SourceFileLoader` is available here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1013

Builtin modules are special cases: because they're implemented in C inside the CPython interpreter they've got `"built-in"` set in their `co_filename` field. That's done here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L725

But unfortunately there's no way of setting an arbitrary name for a module that has been imported.

It would even not be desireable to replace the source file path as it would make debugging more difficult without the source file path from the traceback.

Comment: I know it's an old question but it deserves a proper updated (3.9) answer.